# Python: How to call a function in a script to be called in a different venv?

Tags: python, virtualenv

Assume:

file1.py

```
from file2 import foo
print("python3!")
file2.foo()
```

file2.py

```
def foo():
    print "python2!"
```

I want file1.py to run with a python3 venv (located at `c:/path/to/python3/python.exe`) and file2.py to run with a python2 venv, (located at `c:/path/to/python2/python.exe`)

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Update file2 to python3

Comment: Well, not like this. It's going to be *one* Python interpreter running and interpreting this code. You'd have to make an external system call ("through the command line") to invoke a separate Python process.

Comment: @deceze This makes it very difficult to debug code which was called by my code, but made by someone else using a debugger. I don't want a huge dependency list on my interpreter, thus forcing me to have two separate interpreters. Isn't there any other way?

Comment: You can't run part of your code in Python 3 and another part of it in Python 2. Just no. If you want that, there's necessarily going to be a break between those two.

Comment: @deceze Is this also true for same python, but different venvs?